# Why does XORing two large binary numbers give a decimal output?

Tags: bash

I am trying to XOR two large binary values. However,

```
echo ${hashArray[1]}
echo ${hashArray[2]}
echo $((${hashArray[1]} ^ ${hashArray[2]}))
```

gives:

```
10100100000111101011100001101110000110000100001000000111001001100010110000010010111101100110111001111100010010000000010101110111

00001110110000010110101101011011100101101000011100011101001101101010000100110001001110101101111100010001111010100011010000000100

4018181242766406943
```

Why does `echo $((${hashArray[1]} ^ ${hashArray[2]}))` output a decimal number? Shouldn't it be another large binary value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it "bitwise" like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="101"
b="011"

out=""
for ((i=0; i < ${#a}; i++ )); do
   out=${out}$((${a:$i:1} ^ ${b:$i:1}))
done

echo ${a} ^ ${b} = $out
```

output:

```
101 ^ 011 = 110
```

edit: The inputs need to have the same length!

Answer (score 5):

*bash* does have [support for binary numbers](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/numerical-constants.html), however your numbers are too big and will be truncated. Either do as *mana* suggests or split up the string or use a library that can handle arbitrary precision, e.g. perl's Math::BigInt comes to mind:

*xor.pl*

```perl
use Math::BigInt;

$x = Math::BigInt->new("0b" . $ARGV[0]); 
$y = Math::BigInt->new("0b" . $ARGV[1]);

print $x->bxor($y)->as_bin;
```

Assign the numbers to variables for convenience:

```
x=10100100000111101011100001101110000110000100001000000111001001100010110000010010111101100110111001111100010010000000010101110111
y=00001110110000010110101101011011100101101000011100011101001101101010000100110001001110101101111100010001111010100011010000000100
```

Run with:

```
perl xor.pl $x $y
```

Output:

```
0b10101010110111111101001100110101100011101100010100011010000100001000110100100011110011001011000101101101101000100011000101110011
```

Answer (score 0):

Do bitwise with **bc**, firstly get the file logic.bc :

```
wget http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/code/logic.bc
```

Test xor()

```
x=10100100000111101011100001101110000110000100001000000111001001100010110000010010111101100110111001111100010010000000010101110111
y=00001110110000010110101101011011100101101000011100011101001101101010000100110001001110101101111100010001111010100011010000000100

echo "ibase=2;obase=2;xor($x,$y)" | bc -l logic.bc
```

Result:

```
10101010110111111101001100110101100011101100010100011010000100001000110100100011110011001011000101101101101000100011000101110011
```